# Como copiar attr da página para área de transferência com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, área-de-transferência

Tem um elemento de uma página (**attr**) que quero copiar para área de transferência (Ctrl+C) automaticamente sempre que eu entrar nela. Já consegui buscá-lo com JQuery.
Na página está assim:

```
<div class="image-constrain js-image-wrap image-constrain_zoommed">
    <img class="image__pic js-image-pic" src="https://ig.img.com/image/E0SlHdTiS-SLAGDD3o3aOw.png" alt="" id="screenshot-image" image-id="gqgn5p">
</div>
```

No script está assim:

```
var divACopiar = $('.image-constrain').find('img').attr('src');
```

Pondo pra exibir em console ele se mostra assim:

```
https://ig.img.com/image/E0SlHdTiS-SLAGDD3o3aOw.png
```

Só não encontrei comandos que funcionassem para essa minha necessidade, mesmo aqui nas respostas da comunidade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não consegue setar diretamente para a área de transferência, primeiro você tem que criar um campo oculto qualquer, lembrando que ele não vai funcionar se for do tipo hidden, ou com a propriedade display:none, width:0 ou height:0, por exemplo:

```
<input id="temp" type="text" name="temp" value="">
```

Para ocultar utilize este css:

```
#temp{
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  width:1px;
  height:1px;
}
```

Então você seta o valor neste campo:

```
$('#temp').val('O que vai ficar na area de transferencia');
```

Agora você seleciona o texto do campo:

```
$('#temp').select();
```

Ai sim, você joga para a área de transferência:

```
document.execCommand('copy');
```

Fiz um exemplo para você entender melhor: https://jsfiddle.net/wictor/tyLnu67a/2/

Html:

```
<input id="temp" type="text" name="temp" value="">
<input id="botao" type="button" value="Enviar">
```

Css:

```
#temp{
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  width:1px;
  height:1px;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#botao').click(function(){
        $('#temp').val('O que vai fioicar na area de transferenciddda');
      $('#temp').select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
  });
});
```

Comment: +1. Porém... esse tipo de ocultação pode ser considerado um ataque e eventualmente será proibido pelos navegadores, então fica o aviso a quem for implementar. O recomendável é que fique claro para o usuário o que será copiado para a área de transferência. Fora isso, resposta perfeita.

Comment: Era o que eu procurava, Wictor!  Muito bom! Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos, pessoal!!! E ciente do risco @Renan. ;)